# What happened to Victor von Doom after the accident?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, fantastic-four-2015

In the Fantastic Four 2015 movie,

> Von Doom gets stuck on Planet Zero because he falls into a pit of green neural goo. He says as it is happening that the goo and the planet are alive. Then we see him next a year or two later (earth time) and he has strong telekinetic powers, among other changes. He has also gone from simply being disaffected to becoming sociopathic and hell bent on destroying the earth.

What happened to Von Doom? What did he fall in and why did it change him?

---

**Follow Up:**

---

I am adding a follow up to the answer below as an edit so that I can conceal the spoiler. I would think that there would be interviews with writers and producers about this because:

> a planet with no distinction between biological tissue and its physical surroundings would be a really cool selling point. The planet is a living entity. It has neural tissue that looks like green molten lava. Biological tissue blends with everything, including rocks, fire, etc. The longer an organism stays there, the more of the planet blends into them. The Four each got pieces of it because they were only there for a while. Von Doom got more of it because he was there for longer. It seems like the green neural lava bestows more of it because the Four changed the first time when it was there but did not change when it was concealed during the second visit. So we are talking about the anatomy and physiology of a living entity in the form of a planet that blends with any organism that reaches its neural tissue.

Haven't there been any interviews discussing this with writers and producers?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: we have no idea. The movie makes no attempt to explain any of the things you're asking about; in fact, the people in-universe don't know any more about

> Planet Zero

than we do, because every attempt to examine and study it goes disastrously wrong.

At best, we can fall back on the source material; what we see in the movie is the analog to the *N-Zone*, which is a key part of the *Ultimate Fantastic Four* comics. This is an alternate dimension with a deadly atmosphere, nearing the end of it's life. It's also the source of the Fantastic Four's powers.

However, as far as I can remember, the comics also never explain *how* the N-Zone grants powers to the heroes, and there's nothing quite the same as the substance in the movies there. So, unless we happen to get a sequel to explain things, I don't think we'll ever know.

Comment: I have never seen anything. You have obviously put way more thought into it than anyone working on the movie did.

Comment: I'm also curious. I doubt anyone will bother asking, though. I doubt anyone will care.